# field is optional but it's shown as required on portal

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-365

I have a form on the portal which has some fields, those fields are all set to optional but on the portal they are required.

I don't know what makes them required.

There is no js code involved.
There are no business rules.

What should be the next thing I check ?

Comment: also I have three environments dev,preprod and prod, everything is the same in every env, but in dev and preprod those fields work as intended and they are really OPTIONAL

Comment: look for Entity metatda form, there is an option to set field as required or not.
https://www.inogic.com/blog/2018/12/how-to-make-optional-fields-as-mandatory-fields-in-dynamics-365-portal/

Comment: @AnkUser your answer really helped me, but there was nothing in metadata, I found that  in 'Form Options' 'Make All Fields Required' was ticked :@. Thanks <3

Comment: cool let me add this as an answer, it will grab me some points :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look for your Form in Dynamics. There in you can find Entity metada and it does have an option.

If not look directly under Form Options and there you will find **Make All Fields Required**

[article for Reference](https://www.inogic.com/blog/2018/12/how-to-make-optional-fields-as-mandatory-fields-in-dynamics-365-portal/)